# Java file is needed for existed library when generating single jar file via Maven

Tags: java, maven

I added toaster library to my maven project via install command as seen below.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./jtoaster-1.0.5.jar -DgroupId=com.jtoaster -DartifactId=jtoaster -Dversion=1.0.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```

its dependency definition in project pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jtoaster</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtoaster</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

when i want to generate single jar file via maven (assembly:single is defined as goal), it gave an error as seen below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project ozentegre: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: Problem creating jar: JAR entry com/nitido/utils/toaster/Toaster.java not found in z:\maven_repo\repository\com\jtoaster\jtoaster\1.0.5\jtoaster-1.0.5.jar -> [Help 1]
```

maven searched toasted.java file (not class file, in the jar library, only class file exists). how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of installing via mvn , i got a solution by adding local jar file via showing its path in the dependency definition. i added the dependency definition for the jar file to my pom.xml like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nitido</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtoaster</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>D:\javalibraries\jtoaster\jtoaster-1.0.5.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

i solved my problem in this way.